# Where can I find list of all special traits in Scala?

Tags: scala

Special means that they give you functionality which is impossible to get otherwise, so they treat by compiler in special way.
Examples: 'DelayedInit' - convert all init code to main methods, 'Dynamic' - proxy of all methods etc

Comment: A minor point : DelayedInit is the "magical" trait, App just uses it.

Comment: `App` is only "magical" for performance reasons regarding the optimization of constructors on the JVM. You can easily make your own executable trait by giving it a `main(args: Array[String])` method: see for example the (deprecated) `Application` trait.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At present, the only special traits I'm aware of are `DelayedInit` and `Dynamic`.

Anything inheriting from these traits also gets special treatment by the compiler, as with `App`, which subclasses `DelayedInit`.

It's worth noting that *any* trait could potentially be used as a marker by some library, framework, or compiler plugin to "give you functionality which is impossible to get otherwise".  These two are the only traits that are specially recognized by the default *compiler* though.

As well as marker traits, there are some annotations that get treated specially, the `scala.annotation` and `scala.reflect` are good places to find these, there's also the `@specialized` annotation in the `scala` package and several in compiler plugins (such as delimited continuations).

Answer (score 10):

There is also `scala.Singleton`.

It is a `final trait` and cannot be used normally while writing code, but everyone using some a singleton like `object Foo` has already used it indirectly.

`Singleton` is used by the compiler to extend a singleton, therefore:

```
scala> object Foo
defined module Foo

scala> Foo.isInstanceOf[Singleton]
res0: Boolean = true
```